# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - Laravel/Nginx with Docker

Tags: reactjs, laravel, docker, docker-compose, port

I am new to Docker and I have some difficulties understanding what I'm doing wrong.
I tried to create one docker environment to host a React App (Frontend) and a Laravel App (Backend).

React is working like a charm, but Laravel won't work. When I try to access the domain:Port via the Browser I get the error "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - localhost didn't sen any data".

I'd be really glad if someone could help me. I will attach my docker-compose.yml, nginx config and Dockerfile for Laravel.

Thanks in the meantime

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:

    frontend:
      build:
        context: ./app-frontend 
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      environment:
        - watchpack_polling=true
      volumes:
        - ./app-frontend:/app
      networks:
        - app-network

    nginx:
      image: nginx:alpine
      ports:
        - "8000:80"
      volumes:
        - ./app-backend:/var/www
        - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      depends_on:
        - backend
        - appdb
      networks:
        - app-network

    backend:
      build:
        context: ./app-backend/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      working_dir: /var/www
      volumes:
        - ./app-backend:/var/www
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
      networks:
        - app-network
        - db

    appdb:
      image: mysql:5.7
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      volumes:
        - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      networks:
        - app-network
        - db

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: appdb
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      depends_on:
        - appdb
      ports:
        - 8443:80
      networks:
        - db

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  db:
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name yourdomain.com;  # Change to your domain or localhost

    root /var/www/public;  # Path to your Laravel public directory

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass backend:9000;  # PHP-FPM server address and port
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
########################################################################
### Composer

FROM composer:2.6.2 AS composer

COPY composer.json /app
COPY composer.lock /app

RUN composer install        \
    --ignore-platform-reqs  \
    --no-ansi               \
    --no-autoloader         \
    --no-interaction        \
    --no-scripts

COPY . /app/
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --classmap-authoritative

### Composer
########################################################################
### NodeJS

FROM node:20.6.1-alpine3.18 AS node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json           /app
COPY package-lock.json      /app
COPY webpack.mix.js         /app
COPY /resources             /app/resources

RUN npm install && npm run dev

### NodeJS
########################################################################
### PHP

FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.18

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    libpng-dev                       \
    freetype-dev                     \
    oniguruma-dev                    \
    libxml2-dev

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

COPY . /var/www
COPY --from=composer /app/vendor                /var/www/html/vendor
COPY --from=node     /app/public                /var/www/html/public/
COPY --from=node     /app/mix-manifest.json     /var/www/html/mix-manifest.json


RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www-data

COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

### PHP
########################################################################
```

I tried playing around with the ports and different images, but nothing was successful. http://localhost:8000 always shows the same error.
I also checked if the ports where blocked by another system or firewall, but that wasn't the case.

EDIT:
This is what docker compose ps returns:

ims_mk-appdb-1 | mysql:5.7 | "docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld" | appdb | 55 seconds ago | Up 38 seconds | 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp

ims_mk-backend-1 | ims_mk-backend | "docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm" | backend | 55 seconds ago | Up 36 seconds | 8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp

ims_mk-frontend-1 | ims_mk-frontend | "/bin/sh -c 'npm start'" | frontend | 55 seconds ago | Up 43 seconds | 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp

ims_mk-nginx-1 | nginx:alpine | "/docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g 'daemon off;'" | nginx | 51 seconds ago | Up 26 seconds | 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp

ims_mk-phpmyadmin-1 | phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin | "/docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground" | phpmyadmin | 51 seconds ago | Up 26 seconds | 0.0.0.0:8443->80/tcp

Comment: A couple of things are going wrong. First you want to get things working, so: 'expose' your port 8000. Place the `expose: 8000` in your docker-compose.yml and then `EXPOSE 8000` in your Dockerfile (maybe it's duplicate). The second thing going wrong is: you're copying your source to the docker container, you don't need tl do that, you already have a volume with your source

Comment: Hi, thx for your help. I tried to expose the port, but that didn't change anything. I also removed the COPY statements, but then the build crashed :/

Comment: Maybe switch the ports? Port 80 is more common for nginx, then you can make react ... react on port 3000

Comment: I tried that aswell now. It seems that React is running on every port, but Laravel is not. I tried :80, :3000 and :8080. It is always returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
There must be an error in my configuration

Comment: I'm relying on the fact that laravel is the api abd react is consuming that api. What happens when you use Postman? Back to basics. There is a tool called `laradock`, it provides all you need. First make Laravel work, then start your react container and consume laravel ali

Comment: I followed your advice and created a fresh docker configuration, starting with Laravel. I didn't use laradock though. After Laravel worked I created the react container and put it on top. Now everything works. I will pust my new conifg in an answer. Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a fresh docker installation. I don't really know what caused the issue. Anyways if someone is interested, here is my new configuration.

docker-compose.yaml

```html
version: '3.8'

services:

    # Frontend App
    frontend:
      build:
        context: ./frontend 
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      environment:
        - watchpack_polling=true
      volumes:
        - ./frontend:/app

    # Web Server Service
    nginx:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: nginx
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      volumes:
        - ./backend:/var/www
        - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      depends_on:
        - backend_app
        - db

    db:
      image : mysql
      container_name : mysql
      volumes:
        - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: backend
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

    # Application Service
    backend_app:
      container_name: backend
      build: 
        context: ./php
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./backend:/var/www
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
      working_dir: /var/www

    #phpMyAdmin Service
    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      ports:
        - "3400:80"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

dockerfile:

```html
FROM php:8.2.11-fpm

# Install composer
RUN echo "\e[1;33mInstall COMPOSER\e[0m"
RUN cd /tmp \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update

# Install useful tools
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog vim

# Install important libraries
RUN echo "\e[1;33mInstall important libraries\e[0m"
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing \
    apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    git \
    curl \
    libcurl4 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    libbz2-dev \
    locales \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev
```

nginx config:

```html
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.htm index.html;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/public;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /index.php {
      try_files $uri = 404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass backend_app:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

  }
}
```